# removing sample from a Pytorch dataset object

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm loading images to pytorch using:

```
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=transform)
```

Which has some samples I want to omit.

Can i remove certain images from the loader? (by index? by name?)
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `imgs` attribute of an `ImageFolder` as follows:

```
train_data.imgs.remove((PATH, INDEX))
```

where you should replace `PATH` with the path to the image you wish to remove and `INDEX` should be replaced with the respective class index (starting from 0 to the number of classes you have).
In case you are not sure about the `INDEX` you can print `train_data.imgs` to obtain the list of all image paths with their classes in tuples.